# How to Disable past days in DateTimePicker reactjs

Tags: reactjs, calendar

Hiii Friends I'm using DateTimePicker module to display Calendar. How to disable 
    past days before today's date?

```
<DateTimePicker
ref="from"
calendarOnly={this.state.calendarOnly}
onChange={this.handleChange}
dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
placeholder="From Date"
value={this.state.date}
id="change_handler_example"
showClearButton={this.state.showClearButton}
showTodayButton={this.state.showTodayButton}
/>


I tried Using
const today = new Date(); 
<DateTimePicker minDate={today}/> //it didnt worked
```

Answer (score 0):

minDate is expected to be a moment object.

```
minDate={moment().toDate()}
```

I am pretty sure it would work without calling toDate() as well.

Comment: Actually thier is no propType named 'minDate' in datetimepicker module

Comment: I don't know which one you are using, I am using material-ui/DatePicker and you can effectively apply a minDate.

Answer (score 0):

**how to disable calendar previous date in reactjs **

{{ disabledDays: {before: new Date()} }}

Try this it's working.

Comment: There is no `disabledDays` prop on [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-datetime-picker#props).

Answer (score 0):

```
minDate={new Date()}
```

For more visit: https://reactdatepicker.com/